# Is it possible to run old apps on newer versions of Android? If so, how?

Tags: applications, operating-system

I'd like to run an older app that is no longer compatible with my current OS. However, I don't want to set my device back to an older OS. Is there any way to make old apps work with a newer OS, or is an older OS my only option?

Comment: How do you know that the app is not compatible with your current OS? In general Android OS versions can't be downgraded unless you are running an unlocked/rooted device.

Comment: The app is no longer available in the current play store, and crashes when I try to run it on the current OS. I do know how to downgrade my device, I just don't want to.